# Javascript input into <a href="http://www.website.com/OUTPUT HERE

Tags: javascript, web

```
document.write('<a href=" + x + ">  hello </a>');
```

I have the values for X printing successfully. However, I can't get them to print into this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not closing the string for concatenation.

```
document.write('<a href="' + x + '">  hello </a>');
                         ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead :

```
document.write('<a href="' + x + '">  hello </a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to close your string literal in order to reference a variable x like so:

```
document.write('<a href="' + x + '">  hello </a>');
```